# htaccess - remove page numeric ID

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to direct for a user to type in this URL

http://www.website.com/de/variable-page-name

and have this page show (but browser web address to remain as above URL)

http://www.website.com/de/123/variable-page-name

where 123 is a variable and can contain any number of digits
where variable-page-name is a variable and will have hyphens in

I'm a beginner at this and have tried to read examples but still can't figure it out.
Your help is appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Your question is not very clear since original URL: http://www.website.com/de/somepage doesn't have 123 or variable-page-name you want in destination URL.

Comment: Thanks anubhave, updated the original URL.

Answer (score 0):

Where will the variable 123 come from? what is the variable input to compute 123?

you can do the following

```
RewriteRule de/(.+) de/123/$1
```

than de/somepage will be redirected to de/123/somepage.

In addition of course you can do redirects without htaccess on server side using php

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule: (it won't change the URL in the browser)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/de/(.+)$ de/123/$1 [QSA,L]
```